# Find a function such that $ f(A_1 \cap A_2) \subsetneqq f(A_1) \cap f(A_2) $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I got this problem that I really cannot solve:

We must find a function $ f: X \to Y $ such that there exist two subsets $A_1$ and $A_2$ such that $ f(A_1 \cap A_2) \subsetneqq f(A_1) \cap f(A_2) $.

It is easy enough to prove that  $f(A_1 \cap A_2) \subseteq f(A_1) \cap f(A_2)  $.

Besides, we cannot say that $f(A_1 \cap A_2) = f(A_1) \cap f(A_2)  $, since $f(A_1 \cap A_2) \supseteq f(A_1) \cap f(A_2)  $ is not always the case.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Did you read your post before posting it? You're after a proof of the fact that a set is different from itself.

Comment: Do you mean one of them to be $f(A_1 \cap A_2)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you to go for the simplest example you can find. A quite trivial one is a constante function and two sets that don't intersect. Like the following:

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x):=1 \space \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Let $A_1 := (0,1)$ and $A_2:= (2, 3)$

It's easy to see that $A \cap B= \emptyset$, thus $f(A \cap B) = \emptyset$, however $f(A_1) \cap f(A_2) = \{1\}$

Comment: Maybe you should add that you corrected the OP...

Comment: @mrtaurho Where did I?

Comment: The original post read as $f(A_1) \cap f(A_2) \subsetneqq f(A_1) \cap f(A_2)$ instead of the now corrected $f(A_1 \cap A_2) \subsetneqq f(A_1) \cap f(A_2) $. By the way, now your example fails.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=x^2, A_1=[1,2], A_2=[-2, -1]$.